# Can not feed when using Dataset with MonitoredTrainingSession in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have below code with `tensorflow 1.3.0`. You can run it without any error.
But if uncomment `tf.summary.scalar('test', next_batch)` and `checkpoint_dir='/temp'`,

I got

`InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype string
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_STRING, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]`.

What's wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()
    dataset_train = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.range(10)
    dataset_val = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.range(90, 100)

    iter_train_handle = dataset_train.make_one_shot_iterator().string_handle()
    iter_val_handle = dataset_val.make_one_shot_iterator().string_handle()

    handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
    iterator = tf.contrib.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(
        handle, dataset_train.output_types, dataset_train.output_shapes)
    next_batch = iterator.get_next()
    # tf.summary.scalar('test', next_batch)

    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
            # checkpoint_dir='/temp',
    ) as sess:
        handle_train, handle_val = sess.run([iter_train_handle, iter_val_handle])

        for step in range(10):
            print('train', sess.run(next_batch, feed_dict={handle: handle_train}))

            if step % 3 == 0:
                print('val', sess.run(next_batch, feed_dict={handle: handle_val}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the answer from github. by @asimshankar.

> That said, `MonitoredTrainingSession` runs the summary operations and
>   since your summary operation is connected to the placeholder, it is
>   complaining about the missing feed.
>
> If you do not want the features of the `MonitoredTrainingSession`,
>   might I suggest using `MonitoredSession` or `Session` directly.
>
> Closing this out since it is not a bug or feature request
>   (`MonitoredTrainingSession` intentionally tries to run summary
>   operations at periodic intervals).

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use `MonitoredTrainingSession` then a workaround for this issue is to use `tf.placeholder_with_default`. Use a sensible initial default value and then update it as required.